# pipenv lock -r . Error: No such option -r

Tags: pipenv, python-3.10, requirements.txt

There seems to be some issue with pipenv lock. I used to update the requirements file by running `pipenv lock -r | sed 's|https://.*@nexus|https://${PYPI_USER}:'"'"'${PYPI_PASSWORD}'"'"'@nexus|g' | tee requirements.txt`. I however observed that this doesn't work anymore. Is there an alternative that I could use. pipenv lock --help does not list this option -r anymore.
I'm usiong pipenmv version  2022.10.10 and pip version 21.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained here, it's replaced by pipenv requirements > requirements.txt

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5253#issuecomment-1214344569

Comment: I ended up reverting back to the old pipenv version, but thank you .